# How do I reduce the Windows Security or Log Off page list to only list one thing - "Log Off" - in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, security

How do I reduce the Windows Security or Log Off page list to only list one thing - "Log Off" - in Windows 7? I remember seeing the list somewhere - Registry maybe - a comma delineated list. I don't kow if that was the place to change it or only the list for the registry key that was generated through some other method from the control panel. I only want it to list log off, not change password, switch user or the other possibilities. I've seen it this way on some computers. That way I can simply hit Control Alt Delete and then Return to quickly go to the page that shows the other users like Administrator. Thank you.

Comment: If your goal is to quickly get to the page to log in a different user, try Win+L.

Answer (score 0):

You can use group policy to remove the commands for shutting down and/or rebooting...

Specifically check out the `User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar > Remove and prevent access to the Shut Down, Restart, Sleep, and Hibernate commands` policy.

I don't believe there's a way to prevent the Change Password from showing up, but you can deny a user's ability to change their own password via the user account manager.